# RabbitMQ connection.abort() vs connection.close()

Tags: java, rabbitmq

What is the difference between closing and aborting a RabbitMQ connection?  The Java Docs API  guide uses the same description for each.  This code seems to leave the connection open (and create a new one):

```
if(!connection.isOpen())
{
   connection.abort();
   connection = factory.newConnection();
}
```

Is close possible a graceful shutdown, but abort immediate?

Comment: Are you sure its behavior is different than connection.close()?

Comment: abort calls close under the covers it just ignores exceptions. maybe you are looking for something else?

Comment: Thank you these comments are helpful - I might be diving down the wrong rabbit hole...

Comment: Looking at your other question one more thing that could be helpful you should not create a connection/channel with each request. They are designed to be long lived objects. I don't specifically know how java client works but the explosion of threads in your question is probably related to it.

Comment: Yes, you are in part correct.  The application tries to reuse a connection  across multiple Tomcat sessions.  For some reason when the sessions timeout the connection thread seems to remain active but unable to be used and the code generates a new connection - resulting in an explosion of threads - so my questions are all related.

Comment: Note that in most clients channels create separate threads too. Because it has to wait channel close ok message from server its threads may not terminate immediately.  In your code it seems you are creating and destroying a channel for each request